# VMWare Unity on Windows 7 RC (Host) with Ubuntu 9.04 (Guest)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vmware-workstation, vmware-unity

I'm currently running the Windows 7 RC and trying to use VMWare Workstation's Unity feature with a Ubuntu 9.04 guest.  Unity starts, and I can access the Unity "Start Menu" for Ubuntu within Windows, but when I launch an application, it does not appear in Windows.  Interestingly, if I exit Unity, all the apps I launched (which didn't appear) are open within Ubuntu.  Does anyone know how to get Unity working on Windows 7 RC?

- Host: Windows 7 RC (x64)
- Guest: Ubuntu 9.04 (x64)
- VMWare Workstation 6.5.3
- VMWare Tools 7.8.6 (Current)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not alone:  http://communities.vmware.com/thread/170546

Seems to be an issue with Vista x64 and Windows x64 with Nvidia cards.

Comment: It is also possible that Sprint's SmartView software (for the 3G USB modems) may also be a factor.